# Unsubscribes per business unit

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

Good day to everyone.
Can somebody explain reasons why query for __BusinessUnitUnsubscribes returns 0 rows?
Query looks like this

```
SELECT
 BusinessUnitID businessUnitMID
,SubscriberKey
,SubscriberId
FROM _BusinessUnitUnsubscribes
WHERE BusinessUnitID=1
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: are you capturing unsubs at the BU level? https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_unsubscribe_settings.htm&type=5

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried to test that query on enterprise level. As I understood this is the reason of 0 rows, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The _BUUnsubscribes data view is and thus the query should, be in Parent BU. Which it already is in your case.

a) Does your sending (child) BU have the setting under admin / Business Units set to "unsubscribe from this BU only"?

b) does it have processes in place that perform logUnsubEvents on that Child BU level? You should at least get list unsubscribes, unless you send transactionally classified communication only.

Note also that in contrast to _Unsubscribes, the _BUUnsubscribes Data View does not hold Events, but statuses, so you need to have someone currently on status "unsubscribed" in order to see them appear there. - see here [Query Unsubscribes from a specific MID during a specific Period](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/315601/query-unsubscribes-from-a-specific-mid-during-a-specific-period/315719#315719)